# Loop through each cell in worksheet a and if value true in in worksheet B to replace cell value with "reserved"

Tags: vba

I am trying to look through data that a user has selected in a listbox, when the user clicks "Reserve offcuts" then all the selected lines of data that I have copied over on sheet "Offcut Basket" is then placed onto the database worksheet which is labled as "wo2" I want my code to then look through each line of column E and if that ID matches the ID on the database sheet it will then input the value as "Snumber" which is the value which is captured from the textbox on the userform in the column next to the ID

my Problem is that my code that looks through each cell is asking for an object, I see that i need to declare the objects meaning on which sheet i need to look through, but just a better understanding of where i have put my loop will be a great help. Thanks everyone

```
Private Sub CommandButton11_Click()

'Reserve offcuts with job number

If Offcut11.OffcutJob.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please insert SAGE job number!", vbExclamation, "JDS"
Exit Sub
End If

Dim snumber As String

snumber = Offcut11.OffcutJob.Value

Dim wo1 As Workbook
Dim wo2 As Workbook

Set wo1 = Workbooks("Fabrication Schedule v2")

Do

Set wo2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="J:\Database\Offcut Database.xlsx")
If wo2.ReadOnly Then Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
Loop Until Not wo2.ReadOnly

Application.Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

wo1.Activate
Sheets("Offcut Basket").Activate
Range("A2:F200").Copy

wo2.Activate
Sheets("Offcut Basket").Activate
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Dim acr As String

Dim v As Range
Set v = Worksheets("Offcut Basket").Cells(Worksheets("Offcut Basket").Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)
With Worksheets("Offcut Database")
    For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(2, "E"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
        If Int(cell.Value2) = Int(r.Value2) Then
            Cells(v.Row, 2).Select
            acr = ActiveCell.Row
            Cells(acr, "F").Value = snumber
        End If
    Next cell
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wo2.Save
wo2.Close
wo1.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Offcuts have been reserved", vbExclamation, "JDS"

End Sub
```

Comment: "r" does not seem to be defined >Int(r.Value2)<  Add Option Explicit at the top before Private

Comment: Thanks. I will try tomorrow morning and paste revised code if working.

Comment: @donpablo Got it working, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,

```
Private Sub CommandButton11_Click()

'Reserve offcuts with job number

If Offcut11.OffcutJob.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please insert SAGE job number!", vbExclamation, "JDS"
Exit Sub
End If

Dim snumber As String

snumber = Offcut11.OffcutJob.Value

Dim wo1 As Workbook
Dim wo2 As Workbook

Set wo1 = Workbooks("Fabrication Schedule v2")

Do

Set wo2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="J:\Database\Offcut Database.xlsx")
If wo2.ReadOnly Then Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
Loop Until Not wo2.ReadOnly

Application.Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

wo1.Activate
Sheets("Offcut Basket").Activate
Range("A2:F200").Copy

wo2.Activate
Sheets("Offcut Basket").Activate
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Dim acr As String

Dim v As Range
Dim Found As Range

Set v = Sheets("Offcut Basket").Range("E1", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In v

Sheets("Offcut Database").Activate
Set Found = Sheets("Offcut Database").Range("A2", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find(cell, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Cells(Found.Row, 2).Select
acr = ActiveCell.Row

Cells(acr, "F").Value = snumber

Next cell

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wo2.Save
wo2.Close
wo1.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Offcuts have been reserved", vbExclamation, "JDS"

End Sub
```